# Consuming rate-limiting API

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, rate-limiting, azure-cognitive-services

I have to deal with an external API that is **rate-limited**. This is, if I call the API more than a number of times per second I'll get an exception. The cool thing is that inside the exception, **the service specifies the number of seconds to wait before placing another call**.

In my case, I have an observable that works against that service using a construct like this

```
obs.SelectMany(i => service.CallAsync(i))
```

How could I be aware of the RateLimitExceptions and delay the next call by the number of seconds that the service says into the exception?

Thank you!

This is about creating a sequence that autolimits itself, the other question proposed as duplicate is about ROUTING + limiting. While it sounds similar, I don't enter in the details on how this could be implement, while here it's exclusively about Rx, with no async/await involved.

**EDIT:** The API I'm consuming is Microsoft's Cognitive Services Face API (https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236)

MS provides a Nuget package (**Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face**) with a client (FaceApiClient) with all the operations as async methods. For instance:

```
Task<Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face.Contract.Face[]> DetectAsync(string imageUrl, bool returnFaceId = true, bool returnFaceLandmarks = false, IEnumerable<FaceAttributeType> returnFaceAttributes = null);
```

The **exception** is a FaceAPIException with has a Message like:
"Rate limit is exceeded. Try again in 26 seconds." with an ErrorCode 429.

My objective is to take a bunch of images, detect the faces in each of them and identify each face.

```
identifications = foreach image in Images
        select detection in Detect(image)
        select identification in Identify(detection)
```

Comment: Could you show us all of the relevant code, including the class defs for the API call(s) and the exception?

Comment: Thanks, @Enigmativity. I've added more details to the original message.